# Django model save not working in daemon mode but working with runserver

Tags: django, gunicorn, daemon

I am saving github repo to server once user add their github repo, see this models.

```
class Repo(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(help_text='github repo cloneable',max_length=600)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # os.system('git clone https://github.com/somegithubrepo.git')
        os.system('git clone {}'.format(self.url))
        super(Repo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everything is working fine what I want in both local server and remote server like digitalOcean Droplet, when I add public github repo, the clone always success.

it works when I run the server like this: `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:800`

But when I ran in daemon mode with gunicorn and nginx, it doesn't work,

Everything is working even saving the data in database, only it is not cloning in daemon mode, what's wrong with it?

this is my gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myproject
Environment="PATH=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-9citYRnS/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/myproject/config.sock -m 007 myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note again, everything is working even the gunicorn, the data is saving in database, only it is not cloning github repo, even not firing any error.\

What's the wrong with this? can anyone please help me to fix the issue?

Comment: So are you cloning repositories directly into the project's root directory as the root user? Could you check the current directory before the cloning with e.g. `os.getcwd()` and also check whether this directory is writable.

Comment: Yes, i have checked, the current directory is `/var/www/analytics`

Comment: Could you try with `subprocess.run('git clone {}'.format(self.url), check=True)`? This [will raise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and error in theory if the clone was unsuccessful.

Comment: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git clone https://mygithubrepoop.git /var/www/analytics/external-1'`
I am getting this error

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `run` requires arguments as a list in non-shell mode: `subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', self.url], check=True)`. (Or set `shell=True`.)

Comment: Same error when i set both,

Comment: and when i set shell=True, it doesnt fire error but not cloning

Comment: So the `self.url` is not just an URL but the destination path as well? Is the destination directory `/var/www/analytics/external-1` writable?

Comment: I think it is writable, coz, when I run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` it works very well, can you please let me know how can I give write permission there

Comment: I have given written permission, yet, it doesn't  work

Comment: Strange. Could you try `run` with `capture_output=True` to see what is the output of the git command? Apparently it's not failing and not cloning at the same time.

Comment: Brother, i have debugged everything, the issue is not worth gunicorn, the issue with when we run it in daemon mode

Comment: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git'` this error now I getting

Comment: Maybe as the root user, you have to use the absolute path of the `git` command? E.g. `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: It works, thanks for your time, much appreicated

Comment: Great! Just for the record, I made a summary in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the systemd unit file, you overwrite the root user's `PATH` variable in `Environment` with the path of the virtualenv. Therefore the root user does not have the usual items in the `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/bin` where the git command usually exists. So you need to use the absolute path of git, e.g. `/usr/bin/git`, or add the git's bin directory to the `PATH`, for example:

```
Environment="PATH=/usr/bin:/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-9citYRnS/bin"
```